# Problems with ordering sql server order by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

Check Image

I have a problem with an order by sql server, I need to sort the records in the Ejey field, as follows:

1. Alta/Deficiente
2. Baja/Optima
3. Deficiente/Deficiente
4. Media/Alta
5. Optima/Deficiente

.... So Suspensively

As shown by the selected records in gray, I clarify that my table of the image has 625 records and the other fields must remain the same.

Comment: And why doesn't `order by ejey` do what you want?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: If I order it by the field EjeY does not do it correctly.

Comment: You want put that five records in the first positions of results and then the other records?

Comment: That should be the records

[This][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6mBd.png

Comment: What you describe sounds like an alphabetic order by Ejey (i.e. all Alta/... come first, then all Baja/..., etc.) Now you show an image with rows sorted strangly with five sorted rows first, then another five, then another five, etc. What rule does apply here? Could I switch row #1 with row #6 in your image (both Alta/Deficiente) or would that violate some rule? Where are Alta/Alta etc. in the image? I would have supposed Alta/Alta to be the topmost row in your results.

Comment: That should be the records [This][1] [1]: i.stack.imgur.com/o6mBd.png

Answer (score 0):

As far as each value of EjeY has the same count of rows (5) one idea is to order the rows by the modulo of its row's row number with this count.
This could work:

```
--Save your data in a temp table ordered by the value of EjeY column
SELECT *
INTO #TEMP2 
FROM 
(
SELECT *
FROM YouTable
) AS TEMP1
ORDER BY TEMP1.EjeY --Here you modify the ordering mode you want every time your EjeY values to be displayed

--For each row of the temp table calculate the module the row number 
--with the count of rows per EjeY value 
--(that must be 5 in your situation)
--and order the table by this value and then by row number)

SELECT 
row_col%(select top 1 count(EjeY) from YouTable group by EjeY) AS mod_col, 
row_col,
TEMP3.* --your columns
FROM 
(SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT null))-1 as row_col
FROM #TEMP2) as TEMP3 
ORDER BY mod_col,TEMP3.row_col
```

Comment: That should be the records

[This][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6mBd.png

Comment: Does each value of EjeY  column has the same count of rows?

Comment: These values ​​are repeated every 5 times, just as the image shows.

Comment: It could not use burned values, because the names of the same can vary..


That is, you could not use the case

Comment: Are there any other values in column EjeY except the 5 ones you have referenced?

Comment: Only those values

Comment: in this case you don't need the CASE statement because the ORDER BY clause of the first SELECT statement offers you the desired ordering. Try the new updated answer